# VS2008 MySQL Connector/NET AccessViolationException

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio, access-violation

I've been struggling for weeks with relentless errors thrown either by VS2008 or MySQL Connector/NET.

These errors appear sort of randomly while messing with *Visual Studio's Dataset Designer* and, as soon as it starts, it won't stop; It even prevents from *saving* the XSD file. A pop-up shows:

> *Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

(it turns out to be an `AccessViolationException`, apparently)

That being said, it doesn't seem to be applicable to the infamous remoting bug, since I'm running .NET 3.5 (and cannot install [the fix](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/923028)). I've done a fair amount of research on the net and it pretty much always comes down to this issue.

Furthermore, *sometimes*, one of the following solution will fix the problem temporarily (applied when the previous fails):

- Restarting VS2008;
- Cleaning VS solution;
- Cleaning SVN working copy;
- Re-Checkout SVN;
- Reinstalling MySQL Connector/NET (tried 5.2.6 and 6.0.4);
- Reinstalling VS2008.

(I'm also using AnhkSVN 2.1 if this proves to be relevant.)

Have you ever experienced something similar? Is there a fix or a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrating most of the project to [NHibernate](http://nhforge.org/Default.aspx) (and thus completely avoiding *Visual Studio's Dataset Designer*) was used as a "workaround" (very far around!)

One solution we considered was using another tool to generate typed `DataSets`.
Another potential solution was to manually modify the `DataSet`'s XSD file; However, it proved to be considerably laborious and error prone.

All of these solutions actually involve *not using Visual Studio's Dataset Designer*.